Little girl returns as a ghost to seek justice on her killer, repeats "Why", floats up with balloons
There was a movie I watched in the early 2000's with my mother where a little girl was murdered and a whole team of investigators were trying to solve the case. 
The girl, now a ghost, kept appearing and repeating 'why?' over and over and the investigative team thought she was asking why did the man kill her but it turned out the girl was saying: 'Whye', the surname of the man that killed her and the detectives then solved the murder, locked up the killer and the little girl floated off to heaven carrying balloons. 
The girl couldn't rest peacefully until she had found justice. My mother and I always wondered what the name of that movie was so we could watch it again but, even though I've googled it lots of times, I cannot figure it out. It was a great movie and obviously had an impact! 
Now if I could only find out the name? 

Kinda sounds like the lovely bones, in the sense that the girl is murdered, could go to heaven, but has unresolved issues. The timing is off as are some of the details.It has a ghost, a detective attempting to solve her murder.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lovely_Bones_(film)

I've actually seen The Lovely Bones and I know for sure that's not the movie. I don't think I'll ever find out what it was!

Are you sure the word was 'Whye'?

"Lady in White" I have been trying to remember the title for years! I could remember the killer whistling a song, something like "have you ever heard a bluebird sing ... well I have" and I thought Elijah Wood was on it. JUST now realized it was Lucas Haas and found the title. I pulled it up on VUDU. Enjoy!

Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.
